# Open my own executable in VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I wrote a c# console application in VS2012 and everything was working perfectly so I put the .exe file out on our servers for people to use.

Stupidly before adding it to source control I made some edits to the project and now it's not working.  Is there a way to extract my working code from the working exe file, or am I stuck trying to rebuild from my memory?

Comment: Use a decompiler. [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/), [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), and [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) are good options.

Comment: [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can decompile your .Net code from your executable.

[.Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) does the thing rather well and can even regenerate your entire solution.

Comment: I tried this first and it worked, (see the answer about new variables/comments)  It was enough of the code for me to know where I was before and I just reset the variables to what I wanted and I'm back up and running.  Pretty easy to use, just downloaded and did a file/open and then used the explorer to navigate to my Main program.

Answer (score 1):

[JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) from Telerik will let you extract a project from your existing .net assembly and it is free.

Comment: After trying .NetReflector (which worked), I downloaded the JustDecompile just to try it out and it works too.  Just dragged the .exe file into the browser and navigated to the Main program and pulled what I needed out.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A decompiler will give you "working code", but it won't be "your" working code.

All the comments and local variable names will be gone.  New temporary variables will be added.  And some coding constructs (i.e. whether a loop was `for`, `while`, or `do-while`) may be expressed differently but equivalently.

So, the decompiler is useful to help you confirm your memory (was this change I'm about to check in included in that version or not?), but not for getting back source control-ready code.

Comment: I tried both programs below and was wondering why their output wasn't exactly the same as my original.  It was enough of a memory reminder to know where I needed to get to and I just needed to reformat my variables and re-add some comments for the next person.

Answer (score 0):

I like IlSpy as a free decompiler.  http://ilspy.net/